# Compare multiple columns with IN operator

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Suppose I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE keys (
    keytype INTEGER,
    keyvalue CHARACTER VARYING(30),
    object_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX ix_keys ON keys (keytype, keyvalue);
```

I would like to search for multiple combinations of `keytype` and `keyvalue`. One way to do it is to combine ANDs and ORs, such as:

```
SELECT object_id FROM keys WHERE
    (keytype=1 AND keyvalue='ALICE') OR
    (keytype=1 AND keyvalue='BOB') OR
    (keytype=2 AND keyvalue='5552319912') OR
    (keytype=3 AND keyvalue='938477') OR
    ...
```

However with libraries (currently using Python psycopg2 but could be anyone), I would like to write a single SQL and send a list of tuples as argument. Is there an operator to do that **and still make use of the index**? (I know `IN` only applies to a single column)

I know this doesn't work:

```
find_keys = [
    (1, 'ALICE'),
    (1, 'BOB'),
    (2, '5552319912'),
    (3, '938477'),
]
cursor.execute("SELECT object_id FROM keys WHERE (keytype, keyvalue) IN %s", (find_keys,))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were actually quite close.  Change find_keys to a tuple of tuples:

```
find_keys = (
    (1, 'ALICE'),
    (1, 'BOB'),
    (2, '5552319912'),
    (3, '938477'),
)
cur.execute("SELECT object_id FROM keys WHERE (keytype, keyvalue) IN %s", (find_keys,))
```

You can't use a list because it is translated to an array by psycopg2.  It IS valid to compare sets of objects in postgres.

Comment: I can't believe it was such a silly thing. Even [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR) isn't really clear that this is possible; the expression I made was a lousy attempt to imitate python tuple comparison. But hey, it works!

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL connector, I think you can do this:

```
query = "SELECT object_id FROM keys WHERE (keytype, keyvalue) IN ((%s,%s))"
find_keys = [
    (1, 'ALICE'),
    (1, 'BOB'),
    (2, '5552319912'),
    (3, '938477'),
]

cursor.executemany(query, find_keys)
```